# Butterworth filter not getting as much gain as expected

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, breadboard, active-filter

Using the Analog Devices Filter Design Tool, I have created a band pass filter for a 1MHz input with 20dB of gain. I have implemented the circuit in LTSpice with the expected behaviour, however when I implement it on a breadboard I am not getting the correct amount of gain (but the filtering seems to work when I vary the input frequency).

For my voltage reference I am using a MAX6001 1.25V reference. I have tested this with different bypass capacitors, finding little difference.

My thoughts are that perhaps I have wired the circuit wrong?

Simulated output and circuit:
[image]
[image]

[image: mycircuit]

Output from Picoscope (Red input signal, blue output signal):
[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea how much capacitance sits on that wireless protoboard, between each row? Try wiring all that as dead-bug or manhattan style and see, for starters. Or choose a design that isn't depending upon 47 pF caps. Maybe something at least 10 times larger, maybe more?

Comment: @periblepsis, Interesting, thank you for your reply. Due to the nature of the design, I wish to keep the capacitance low. From what you are saying, the lower than expected gain is from the use of the breadboard, rather than the circuit itself?

Comment: @LK26 what's that requirement that keeps the capacitances low? Note how that also makes the resistors low-ohmic (i.e., "strong"), meaning you're significantly loading the outputs of the opamps, which probably is a bad idea, as well.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I need my design (whole design, not just this circuit) to be intrinsically safe, so wish to keep capacitance low

Comment: 180 MHz op-amps "on breadboard" likely explains it. You need a proper PCB which is designed very carefully to avoid parasitic capacitances and inductances from affecting the performance.

Comment: I didn't analyze your circuit. I see 47 pF caps and come to a full stop. You are probably using high bandwidth/high frequency. Wireless boards should be considered as having small pF from anywhere to anywhere on the board and mostly useless for such things. (It's like setting a circuit down on top of a block of conductive carbon and complaining about the stray currents you are finding.)

Comment: @LK26 I must admit I don't understand. What kind of safety are you referring to? What does the magnitude of signal-path capacitors have to do with safety?

Comment: Intrinsic safety requirements at these sort of DC voltages (i.e. low) allow several microfarads of capacitance @LK26 additionally, the feedback resistor value of 15 kohm is about 30 times higher than what is used within various diagrams in the data sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The midband-gain of the 1st stage for the shown circuit for two equal capacitors is (assuming ideal opamp properties): -

**Gmax,1=R5/2R4=4.16 (12.4 dB)**.

Similarly, for the 2nd stage we get

**Gmax,2=22k/5.4k=4.075 (12.2 dB)**

Question 1: Did you use the filter tool correctly (because your design goal was 20dB gain) ?

Question 2: What did you measure for each stage (separately)?

Question 3: Did you check the slew rate of the opamp used?